# "Filter branches by name" showing error in Jenkins Build Trigger

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, webhooks, git-webhooks

"Filter branches by name" in "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab" build trigger is showing below error while providing the branch name in the Include box in jenkins:

**Error:** Following patterns don't match any branch in source repository: qa

I have tried giving */qa, qa, /qa as the branch name but still shows same error.

I guess, Web Hook is configured correctly as job is triggered when "Allow all branches to trigger this job" is selected in jenkins.